# cfssl example certificate chain verification failure

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

I am getting the following error when trying to verify the certificate chain of a dummy root/intermediary/end PKI.

root generated as follows:

```
mkdir {root,inter,end}
cfssl print-defaults config > root/root-config.json
cfssl print-defaults csr > root/root-csr.json
cfssl genkey -initca root/root-csr.json | cfssljson -bare root/root
```

and intermediary:

```
cfssl print-defaults config > inter/inter-config.json
cfssl print-defaults csr > inter/inter-csr.json
cfssl genkey -initca inter/inter-csr.json | cfssljson -bare inter/inter
```

sign the intermediary w/ the root:

```
cfssl sign -ca root/root.pem -ca-key root/root-key.pem inter/inter.csr | cfssljson -bare inter/inter
```

I can verify the intermediary certificate:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root/root.pem inter/inter.pem
inter/inter.pem: OK
```

Then create the end user certificate:

```
cfssl print-defaults csr > end/end-csr.json
cfssl genkey end/end-csr.json | cfssljson -bare end/end
cfssl sign -ca inter/inter.pem -ca-key inter/inter-key.pem end/end.csr | cfssljson -bare end/end
```

I can bundle the certificate chain:

```
mkbundle root/root.pem inter/inter.pem
```

And verify the intermediary cert against it (obv)

```
openssl verify -CAfile cert-bundle.crt inter/inter.pem
inter/inter.pem: OK
```

but when I try to verify the end certificate is a valid certificate in that chain:

```
openssl verify -CAfile cert-bundle.crt end/end.pem
```

I get the following error:

```
C = US, ST = CA, L = San Francisco, CN = example.net
error 7 at 0 depth lookup: certificate signature failure
error end/end.pem: verification failed
139745623078144:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP    lib:../crypto/asn1/a_verify.c:174:
```

I'm using the default csr's and configs:

csr:

```
{
    "CN": "example.net",
    "hosts": [
        "example.net",
        "www.example.net"
    ],
    "key": {
        "algo": "ecdsa",
        "size": 256
    },
    "names": [
        {
            "C": "US",
            "ST": "CA",
            "L": "San Francisco"
        }
    ]
}
```

as well as the default CA configs:

```
{
    "signing": {
        "default": {
            "expiry": "168h"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "www": {
                "expiry": "8760h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth"
                ]
            },
            "client": {
                "expiry": "8760h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the end certificate isn't encoded properly for `openssl verify`. This might have something to me not changing any subject names in the CSR. But was curious if this was a common issue or I'm using the tools wrong.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure theres a few things I'm doing wrong:

1. you only need 1 config for cert chain
2. instead of using `cfssl genkey` use `cfssl gencert` and specify the certificate authority you're issuing the CSR for
3. add 'cert sign' as a "usage" in the profile
4. use unique common names

I didn't work out the exact issues w/ this method but this blog article produced a valid certificate for me:

https://propellered.com/2017/11/13/cfssl_setting_up/